# Programming vba excel to move cursor

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out how to move a cursor from one excel cell to another with a specific shortcut using vba for excel.
say from any cell if I press Alt+e it bring me to A5 for exemple. Alt+d would bring me to E3 for example etc... Any help?

Comment: Refer to: http://superuser.com/questions/212583/how-do-you-customize-excel-2010-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a VBA macro like shown below

```
Sub MoveToA5()
    Range("A5").Select
End Sub
```

Then, press ALT+F8, select "Options" and assign the shortcut combination, for example CTRL+Shift+a.

In order to use ALT+ HotKey combination (for example, ALT+F5), place the Macro shown above into code Module (you have to add it to your `Workbook` `VBAProject` using Modules->Insert->Module) and also add the following code snippet to `ThisWorkbook` code module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "%{F5}", "MoveToA5"
End Sub
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but it has to be Alt+e, Alt+d etc. Is there a way to to this in a code insted of Alt+F8 shortcut?

Comment: Please refer to my extended answer. Best regards,

Comment: `Application.OnKey "%{F5}", "MoveToA5" ` works fine, but instead of F5, I need to use a letter like a, b, c, etc... I did a little bit of research on how to code it but not much of a success. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated.